I'm trying to run phpMyAdmin and link it to an existing docker container database and I get an error. (Using Synology NAS w/ Web Station + Docker)
I'm running a Synology NAS to host my PHP website. I'm using Web Station and Container Manager (Docker).
When I create a phpMyAdmin container, link it to the exisiting mariaDB database, and run it, I get this error:
Start container phpmyadmin-1 failed: {"message":"Cannot link to /interjoin-database-1, as it does not belong to the default network"}.

What's going on? How can I fix it? All I'm trying to do is connect to the MariaDB via phpMyAdmin to manage and import my .sql file that I backed up for my PHP website.
I created a containerized project "interjoin" on Container Manager (Docker) running PHP 5.6 and MariaDB. And then I created a new container (i guess not part of the "interjoin" project, since i don't know how to add phpmyadmin container to it) for phpMyAdmin. I made it so that it links to the "interjoin-database-1" MariaDB instance. But when I run the phpMyAdmin container, it gives me this error:
Start container phpmyadmin-1 failed: {"message":"Cannot link to /interjoin-database-1, as it does not belong to the default network"}.

